# How to convert hex value more than 256 in two bytes

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion, hex, byte

I am trying to store hexadecimal value greater than 255(unsigned) into two bytes. Below is the sample code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte b = (byte)0x12c; // output : 44
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Example:  When I convert 300 in hex it will be 12c, which should be shaved as (44, 1) in byte. why java is saving 44 in first byte?

Comment: Where would you want it to go, and why?

Comment: `0x12c` is `0001_0010_1100`. Casting to a `byte` only keeps the least significant `8` bits of the `int`, which is `0010_1100` in your example, which is equal to `44`.

Comment: The same is true when downcasting a `long` to an `int`.  There are many conversion issues which can be gotchas if you are unfamiliar with them.  Read all about them in the Java Language Specification [Kinds of Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1).

Comment: Thanks @ Jacob for your reply. But in case of 400 (instead of 300 0x12c) it prints -112 but it should print 144 and 1 as 0001_1001_0000.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN):
bbuf.putShort((short) 0x12c);

byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN):
bbuf.putInt(0x12c);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

Or you do your calculation yourself.

Here we create the two bytes we want, wrap a ByteBuffer around it, so we can read and write several numeric primitive types. You want little endian byte order (2c first).

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your value into bigger data type (long or int) and then only take first 16 insignificant bits

```
int raw = (int)0x12c;
int masked = raw & 0x00ff
System.out.println(masked);
```